# How to create the .bin and .js model files for Lamborghini Gallardo (in examples)

Tags: webgl, three.js

I'm wondering about how to create the model files for Lamborghini Gallardo (in examples).
I mean this model is very complex and it is stored in many files, e.g.:

```
    .htaccess
    GallardoNoUv_bin.bin
    GallardoNoUv_bin.js

    and in parts folder:
    gallardo_body_bin.bin
    gallardo_body_bin.js
    gallardo_wheel_bin.bin
    gallardo_wheel_bin.js
```

How to create these files? So if I have my model in Blender or Maya how could I export/convert my model into the above format? Why is this model separeted into many .js and .bin files?

So, could someone write for me please the steps how to convert my models into this format?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export **.obj** files from most 3D softwares, then convert those to **.js/.bin** files using this Python command-line script :
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py